# Mantener sesión iniciada en Unity - Firebase

Tags: firebase, login, app, unity

estoy haciendo una aplicación web en Unity, utilizo Firebase para el registro y acceso de los usuarios. 
Actualmente estoy utilización la autenticación con e-mail y password, el cual funciona bien, pero a la hora de cerrar la aplicación y volverla a abrir me pide acceder de nuevo.

¿Qué debo hacer para lograr mantener la sesión iniciada?

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Mi código del Login es el siguiente:

```
//Acceso de Usuarios
public void Login(string email, string password)
{
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync error: " + task.Exception);
                if (task.Exception.InnerExceptions.Count > 0)
                    UpdateErrorMessage(task.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].Message);
                return;
            }

            FirebaseUser user = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                user.DisplayName, user.UserId);

            PlayerPrefs.SetString("LoginUser", user != null ? user.Email : "Unknown");
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Bienvenida");
        });
}
```